# onclicklistener on Dynamic checkbox and check whether checkbox is checked or not

Tags: android, checkbox, dynamic, onclicklistener

i want to apply `onclicklistener` on dynamic `checkbox`
and check if  the `checkbox` is `click`  then add the `getid` in `ArrayList` and if `checkbox` is unchecked then  remove the `getid` from `ArrayList`

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
 //getting product object from json array
 JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);
 cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
 cb.setText(product.getString("service_name"));
 cb.setId(product.getString("id"));
 cb.setTag(product.getString("id"));
 linearMain.addView(cb);
}


buttons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

  cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (cb.isChecked()) {
     testoo.add(cb.getId());

    } else {
     testoo.remove(cb.getId()); //checkbox unchecked
    }
   }
  });

 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more simpler way available, you do not have to relay on click of `CheckBox`, `CheckBox` To listen check change state in `CheckBox` you can setup listener shown below.

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
                testoo.add(cb.getId());
            else
                testoo.remove(cb.getId());
        }
    });
```